# How to use select count() as ... in C#

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I'm making a simple login page using a database.
So for my queries i'm using Dapper and i'm stuck on following query.

```
connection.Execute(@"SELECT count(Id) as Id FROM tblMedewerkers 
where Naam = @Naam and Paswoord = @Paswoord",
new{
 Naam = naam,
 Paswoord = paswoord
  });
```

So if the part "count(Id) as Id " returns 1 the login is correct.
If it returns 0 it's wrong.

But how do I get the data from "count(Id) as Id" into something to work with?

Comment: Please read the tag text before applying them to your question.  The `visual-studio` tag should only be used when your question is *about* VS, not about general code questions where VS happens to be your IDE.

Comment: As a side note: it is almost always a huge mistake to store passwords. I don't know what your scenario is, but if this is a login system, the usually approach is to store a **salted hash** of the password (where the salt is generated per-row), and compare the *hashes*.

Comment: and before you say "ah, but there's nothing very important in the system - it doesn't matter much if someone breaks in" : **people tend to reuse their passwords between systems**, so a leak of the password from your system could allow an attacker into something much more important. NEVER STORE PASSWORDS (unless you're writing a password manager, and understand encryption)

Comment: I am just trying basic stuff.
Following a class C# and just been trying out stuff for myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Execute` performs a **non-query** operation (usually an `insert` or `delete` that doesn't `select` anything). You want a `Query` method - the most convenient probably being `QuerySingle<int>`, because you expect exactly one value that is an `int`.

```cs
int count = connection.QuerySingle<int>(@"SELECT count(Id) as Id FROM tblMedewerkers 
where Naam = @Naam and Paswoord = @Paswoord",
new{
 Naam = naam,
 Paswoord = paswoord
  });
```

Comment: Could `ExecuteScalar` also be used?

Comment: @SamHaekens if it comes back with a zero rather than throwing an exception, then the database probably reported zero... check the table to see if the record actually is there, and has the expected values; if you're using non-ASCII characters, you may also have code-page problems unless you're using `nvarchar`

Comment: @SamHaekens If Marc's answer helped you, be sure to mark it as accepted.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work